# Spring WebFlow Avoid Page Reload With Empty Transition Target

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I have a question regarding spring webflow
 and I was hoping if someone could tell me
if it is possible to have a "view-state" that when a particular
transition event occurs it remains in the same "view-state" at 
it was before the event, **BUT without** a reload of the page. So basically, given the sample below a transition with an empty "to" will it still cause the page to reload? Is there **any** way to avoid this?

Thanks in advance

```
<view-state id="someState" model="aModelDTO" view="aview">
    <binder>
        <binding property="prop1" required="true"/>
        <binding property="prop2" required="true"/>
        ...
    </binder>
    <transition on="next" to="bla" validate="true"/>
    <transition on="cancel" to="cancel" bind="false"/>
    <transition on="do-nothing" to=""/>
</view-state>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, that is not possible. Entering a transition means that you have submitted a request to the server, and at that point you can't turn back. If the reason to stay in the same transition without reloading is to call some method, you can use Ajax as an alternative that doesn't require to go through the flow.